# Closure of two sets

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $Cl(E\cup F)=Cl(E)\cup Cl(F)$ where $Cl$ is the closure.

I know that $Cl(E\cup F)=(EUF)\cup(E\cup F)'$ where $(EUF)'$ are the limit points of the set. After distribution I get $(E'\cup F)\cup(E \cup F') \cup (Cl(E) \cup Cl (F))$. Am I going about this the wrong? Thanks

Comment: As the other answer says, "element chasing" is definitely the way to go here

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier to show in the following way. If $p\in (EUF)$, then, $p\in E$ or $p\in F\implies p\in Cl(E)\cup Cl(F)\implies E\cup F\subset Cl(E)\cup Cl(F)$. Now, let $p\in (E\cup F)'$. Then, $p\in Cl(E)\cup Cl(F)$ since otherwise, $\exists\epsilon>0$ such that $d(p,x)>\epsilon\forall x\in E\cup F$ which is a contradiction to the assumption that $p\in (E\cup F)'$. Hence, $(E\cup F)'\subset Cl(E)\cup Cl(F)$. Thus, together they give you  $Cl(E\cup F)\subset Cl(E)\cup Cl(F)$. Finally, $E,F\subset E\cup F\implies Cl(E)\cup Cl(F)\subset Cl(E\cup F)$ which completes the proof.